# Please wait for User Profile Service... on WIndows 7 takes around 1-2 minutes to process

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, login

When loggging into our domain, after entering account credentials the log in process takes around 1-2 minutes before it gets past the User Profile Service, the rest of the process takes 2-3 secs.

This effects all machines running Windows 7 Enteprise 32-bit and is on fairly high spec laptops (SSD drives, i5 2.93Ghz CPU, 4GB memory).

Is there any way to speed this up or is this time delay acceptable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using network profiles or folder redirection?

Comment: This is often indicative of a DNS problem

Comment: @jscott folder redirection

Comment: is this logging into the domain for the 1st time on a given workstation or everytime?

Comment: Why not fire up a [sniffer](http://sysadvent.blogspot.com/2010/12/day-10-basic-sniffing-with-tcpdump.html) and see what is going on.

Comment: Connecting the HOMEPATH, which in my case mapped to a Network folder, was causing the delay. I removed that path from my user account in AD, and tried it and it logged on immediately. Any idea what would be the cause of such a delay, and how we would fix it? When logging in, our scheme is to map the Homepath to a users directory on a network server, to store user information. That path is also on a DFS share, I wonder if there is something slow in that transition that is causing problems?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked for Event Log errors during the time of logon on these workstations? Also, I'd recommend turning on Verbose messages via GPO for some workstations you can troubleshoot on to see where it is taking the longest.

In a Computer GPO: Administrative Templates\System\**Display highly detailed status messages** - enable. Run `GPUPDATE /force` and reboot. Now when you logon you'll get more descriptive messages to help in troubleshooting where the delay is.

Comment: I cannot locate this setting in GPO.

Comment: that's the risk you run when you try to follow 6yr old advice :) - check this: http://www.verboon.info/2012/06/the-group-policy-setting-verbose-vs-normal-status-messages-has-a-new-name-in-windows-8/ it's been renamed to Display highly detailed status messages

Answer (score 2):

We have got the “**waiting for the user profile service**” problem solved.

For our case, we are not using roaming user profile but we have found that our AD users have specified Home Drive in network drive. So we just changed the AD user home drive to “Local” (with no drive specified)

To validate where is your home drive and home path is just execute SET command in CMD and browse for HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH. For our case, we want to ensure that it's D:\ and \Users\xxxx

Good Luck.
I am Number 9

Answer (score 0):

Mark probably has it right, about 99% of the time I've seen this the root cause has been something with DNS.

Edit: Heres some basic tips to troubleshoot this particular problem.

Try and ping the server using the FQDN. This should let you know whether or not you've got your local DNS configure correctly.

Verify that you've got the correct dns settings in your local profile. If you don't know what they should be check a PC that is working correctly and just mimic those settings.

If you've got the right DNS server configured one thing that I've often seen has been either a missing or mismatched computer account on the domain. Verify this by comparing the local PC name to what the account is on the server.

I've also had some luck just leaving and rejoining the domain.

@Corey S. - Thanks for the nudge :)

Comment: That's wonderful, but what about throwing him a bone in terms of what to look for in way of DNS issue?

Answer (score 0):

Verify your workstations have DNS IP pointing to your AD servers and not some external IP's.

For example if your internal DNS IP is 192.168.1.16 and 192.168.1.17. You can't use something like google DNS 8.8.8.8. So make sure you use internal DNS servers only and that those DNS servers are Active Directory aware. Having external DNS on your Workstations (even as 2nd IP) can cause serious delays (exactly what you are seeing now).

Answer (score -1):

It is taking bit long in logging becuase it is going to find profile on server. Assign your server IP as DNS on Windows 7 pc. So it will faster able to search server and logging process will be even faster.

Answer (score -2):

Hi friends i am happy to give my wonderful tip for  speedup  user profile under the domain controller.
Please follow the instructions

1. if your a domain user and slow profile loading
2. if your joined under domain controller
3. if your not a administrator profile login

then only you can follow the steps to get faster user profile log in in your laptop or desktop systems:

please enter your server ip address in the following

1. open network connections
2. go to change adapter settings
3. select advanced settings
4. click on DNS Tab
5. Enter your server ip address in the below
6. tick in the box bottom of the window  USE THis connection DNS Suffix registration

I Can proudly saying that you ll get good results

Best of luck my dear admins

Comment: 1. This is completely wrong and will have no effect on profile loading speed. 2. Non-Administrators will not be able to change the DNS settings. 3. Users should not be changing their DNS settings, they should be getting them from DHCP. 4. This question is answered above, the correct answer has nothing to do with network settings.